# nginx + Express: etag caching doesn't work

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

Given a nodejs application with express, which goes through nginx. I'm trying to add cache support with etags.

Without nginx, if the application get called directly it works. I set the If-None-Match Header and receive a 304.

With nginx, the response is always 200.

My Nginx config:

```
    location /app/ {
            proxy_pass http://app;
    }
```

Log entry from express.

> info: HTTP GET /app/ statusCode=200, url=/app/, connection=upgrade,
>   host=11.1.1.1, accept=application/json, text/plain, */*,
>   user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36, 
>   referer=somesite.com, accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.6,
>   if-none-match=W/"29ae92-4sHBxs6sPcMB3/GypUtubLN0HQ8-gzip", 
>   x-forwarded-proto=http, cookie=io=XAMR4ZH1TzxIvWzkAAAA,
>   x-forwarded-for=10.43.212.26,   x-forwarded-host=somesite.com,
>   x-forwarded-server=somesite.com,   method=GET, httpVersion=1.1,
>   originalUrl=/app/,  responseTime=352

Answer (score 0):

You should enable [HTTP/1.1](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_http_version) in the NGINX configuration:

```
location /app/ {
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_pass http://app;
}
```

Comment: Is the `If-None-Match` header passed to Express at all?

Comment: Yes. I added a log entry to my question

Comment: How is the ETag being calculated?

Comment: I have no idea, I guess like described here: stackoverflow.com/questions/24542959/… The etag and the if-none-match header are set correctly and they match each other. (please disregard my former comment about the cache-control header which is actually not set in the request)

Comment: I can't reproduce, to be honest (using nginx/1.12.0 in front of Express 4.15.3). To be honest, the ETag value that the log shows looks weird, as if it's not a regular Express-generated ETag. Is your app using middleware that may be causing this?

Comment: It appears nginx is adding "-gzip" to the tag, which can't work. Directly calling the application returns a etag without "-gzip"

Comment: That's also something I can't reproduce. What's your NGINX `server` config look like?

Comment: Are you calling with something like '"Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br"'?

Comment: Yes, I'm making sure that NGINX actually compresses the response.